# Mock namespaced class with SimpleTest

Tags: php, simpletest, spl-autoload-register

I'm using SimpleTest to unit test my PHP classes. I added a custom base class which does a `spl_autoload_register` to autoload the classes i need.

But now mocking becomes a problem. How can i mock the classes that are loaded through a namespace?

This is basically what i have in my test class.

```
<?php
require_once('../../GGUnitTestCase.php');

Mock::generate('\Core\Routes\GGRoute');

class TestGGRouter extends GGUnitTestCase
{    
    function TestMethod()
    {
        $route = new \Core\Route\GGRoute(); // <-- This loads up fine!

        // But i need a Mock class, not the real one.
        // How to load a Mock in this case?
        $routeMock = new \Core\Routes\MockGGRoute(); // <-- Doesn't work!

        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
?>
```

Anyone any idea how i can still mock the classes loaded through a namespace (autoloaded)?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but no one uses SimpleTest nowadays. Consider switching to PHPUnit. It's the defacto industry standard.

Comment: @Gordon You're probably right, but it i find setting up PHPUnit a hasle with that packet manager. And i'm also working on a hosting account which doesn't let me install any third party apps like that.

Comment: @Vivendi You can download PHP Unit as a PHAR archive, that's a simple ZIP-like file which contains all necessary files used by PHP Unit.

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, that works, thanks. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @ComFreek It seems like the PHP version of my hoster supports Phar files. I'll try to have a look at PHPUnit aswell, Thanks for that advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\` (all but preceding one) in the name of your namespaced Class with `::`. In your example that'll be...

```
Mock::generate('Core::Routes::GGRoute');
```